# My character is hanging in the air after adding a capsule collider

Tags: physics, unity

I am using Unity 5.3. I have added a capsule collider to one of my models. I have added a rigidbody to my character. After rotating and translating my model. the model hangs in the air as shown in images below.

I think it is due to the capsule collider. Does capsule collider not adjust automatically after changing parts of the model, like when animating the model, or is it a fixed collider which does not change after animating the model?

How do I fix this problem?

[image: Before Runtime]
[image: After Runtime]

Comment: I think its worth pointing out that your not just changing the transform or rotation of the *goalkeeper* when you animate. The goalkeeper is likely made up of smaller pieces, including bones and joints. These smaller pieces are transformed to animate the model. Just like adjusting a child object inside a parent object, this has no effect on the parent transform - or the collider attached to it. You can clearly see that in screenshot2, the actual *goalkeeper2* object has been rotated to its side and translated to the right. These two transforms *have* been replicated on the collider.

Comment: As far as I can find, online, you can not use a mesh collider with animation.

Answer (score 1):

The `CapsuleCollider` does not automatically conform to animation. It will conform to the local or inherited transform, but will not change to fit the goalkeeper extending its arms upwards instead of outwards. While there is generally transform manipulation behind the animation, it is performed on the *child* objects, which does not effect the *parent*. We can see this in screenshot two, where the collider has not shrunk to fit the goalkeeper, but has rotated in response to the transform rotation.

I can see two possible solutions; Manually altering the collider via code seems to be the easiest, but the goalkeeper will still appear to float, to some degree. Alternatively, you can place smaller colliders on the individual bones of the goalkeeper, where the animation should directly effect the transform values.

#### Altering the `CapsuleCollider` via code

If you manually alter the dimensions of the `CapsuleCollider` when the goalkeeper changes its state, you should be able to at least create a tighter fit. For instance, when the goalkeeper throws its arms up, you could directly lower the `CapsuleCollider.radius` to constrict the collider to the tighter model.

```
CapsuleCollider collider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
collider.radius = 3.5;
```

It is still going to look like your goalkeeper is floating, to some degree. At the end of the day, you are still using a single 3D primitive to determine the collision of a more intricate 3D model. The difference is that your goalkeeper will slide on the straight space between the leg and the arm, as opposed to the open space left behind by the outstretched arms.

#### Using multiple colliders

If you instead attach smaller colliders to the bones in your animation, you can get away with more precise collision detection, at the cost of processing power. You might want to consider using more than just the `CapsuleCollider`, in this case. For example, the `SphereCollider` would be a better fit for the head, and a `BoxCollider` might be a more efficient way to manage the torso.

Simple apply a collider to each bone where animation is performed, and ensure that the collider appropriately covers the part of the mesh animated through that bone. For example, the shoulder bone would contain a collider for the upper-arm, while the elbow would contain the collider for the forearm and hand, assuming there were no more bones to animate hand movement.

Comment: I tried your technique on both the goalkeeper's arms and after attaching box colliders on both upper and lower arms the box colliders are moving with animation. Thanks for that. I used simple sphere and box colliders on the head and body of the goalkeeper but after running  the head and body colliders are separating from the body and I am getting weird physics. Do you think I should attach these head and body colliders to the bone of that particular part or should this technique be used where animation is taking place. In my model only arms have animation. Rest of the body has no animation.